# Получить конечную сумму из значений всех записей MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица:

```
id | type |  summ
1  | paid |  1000
2  |charge|  5000
3  | paid |  1000
4  |charge|  5000
```

Мне нужно сумму строк charge отнять сумму строк paid, в итоге в этом примере должно получиться 8000. Я могу конечно сделать два запроса в БД, а потом минусовать полученные два значения. Но можно ли это как-то уместить в один запрос более изящно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Где то так

```
select sum(if (`type` = 'charge', summ, -summ)) FROM test.tbl;
```

`test.tbl` - это имя таблицы. Конечно, строковое значения поля - это не очень хорошо, надеюсь там просто числа.

Comment: @KoVadim, Попробовал выполнить запрос, возвращается пустой ответ.
Непонятная логика запроса, почему в ней отсутствует type: paid?!

Comment: @chuikoff, потому что `type = charge` считается с плюсом, а все остальное - с минусом. Совсем пустой ответ странно, движок должен либо сказать, что не понимает запрос, либо вернуть единственное значение.

Comment: @KoVadim,@Fike всё, понял, спасибо большое, разобрался!)